# Elevate privileges while running ClickOnce installer

Tags: c#, clickonce, privileges, administrator

I have developed an application which depends on Crystal Reports runtime.

The problem is that our company domain policies does not allow installing this runtime from an user account. If I install runtime from an admin account separately and then run the ClickOnce installer from user account everything goes ok.

Is it possible to force installer to ask for administrator credentials while installing application?

Answer (score 0):

No, ClickOnce does not support this out of the box.

You can use the [`InPlaceHostManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.inplacehostingmanager.aspx) to create a custom installer or custom installer steps. It involves quite some steps to get it working, but the concept is there.

You can start a new executable with `Process.Start` within the installer, providing the `Verb = "runas"` to make it run as administrator.